# Making a loop wait 5 minutes before executing again

Tags: java, android, google-maps, sleep

So I am writing an Android app and want to have a function that checks for that asks for the location data every minute or so (haven't decided how often yet). 
I know that I could just create a thread and tell it to sleep, but I don't really like that option since I would have to create the thread for that one function then lock it so it can't be used by anything but that one thread.
The other option I've thought of would be to just have an infinite loop that checked if the time had passed, but that raises even more serious issues.

So my question is, is there a better way to make the loop wait a specified period of time before executing again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html):

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final long delay = 5 * 60 * 1000;

void executeSomething(){
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            // do your work

            if (continueToExecute){
                executeSoemthing();
            }
        }
    }, delay);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, not really.  However, the Android platform is designed to support these kinds of things.  Do a little research on Services [Android API page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and Timers [Android API page](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `postDelayed(Runnable,long)` to do this.